# Pythonic way to make a key/value pair a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a situation where I'm getting values returned from MongoDB like this:

```
{'value': Decimal('9.99'), 'key': u'price'}
{'value': u'1.1.1', 'key': u'version'}
```

Now, I came up with a few ways to do this, like (albeit one of my sloppier ones):

```
y[x['key']] = x['value']
```

but I just have this nagging suspicion that there's either a single or a small combination of built-in methods that would clean is up.

Comment: I think `y[x['key']] = x['value']` is pretty concise and readable.

Comment: I'm with aix. I think that this is a perfect opportunity to avoid over-thinking a problem.

Comment: HA, your probably right - not the first time I needed someone to remind me of that. Thanks

Comment: Your solution is what I would have used.  There is no need for further "improvement".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be with [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [{'value': 9.99, 'key': 'price'}, {'value': '1.1.1', 'key': 'version'}]
>>>
>>> getter = itemgetter('key','value')
>>> dict(getter(dct) for dct in lst)
{'price': 9.99, 'version': '1.1.1'}
```

Or using [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html)/[`imap()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) as *gnibbler* suggested:

```
>>> dict(map(getter, lst))
{'price': 9.99, 'version': '1.1.1'}
```

Comment: or `dict(map(getter, lst))`. you can use `imap` for Python2

Comment: @gnibbler: Thanks! I like that more than the others approach, so I've updated it in the answer :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! It's elegant enough that I'll totally deal with having an additional import. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In Python 2.7+, you could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
In [2]: l = [{'value': Decimal('9.99'), 'key': u'price'}, {'value': u'1.1.1', 'key': u'version'}]

In [5]: {x['key']: x['value'] for x in l}
Out[5]: {u'price': Decimal('9.99'), u'version': u'1.1.1'}
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
d = dict((x['key'], x['value']) for x in values)
```

Assuming these values are in some kind of iterateable.

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for more information.